# Forward API Request

Tags: json, rest

I want to develop Mobile App which will provide data from API based on the request. Now the problem is API provider do not allow API Request from app instead they want API Request from single IP of server.
So, How can I forward API Request from app to my server and get JSON response back in app.

Comment: expose the same endpoints on your server with the same design as the real API (or simplified, if you only use a small part of it). Change the base URL that your app sends to to your server name. On your server, gather all the parameters again and create a new web request to the real API. Get the response, and immediately return it to the app unchanged. That's the coded version. You might even be able to do it more simply with some sort of proxy server setup that can just pass on the request but change the referrer (a bit like NAT??), but that's more of a sysadmin job than a coding one.